# Showing variant as individual listings on Homepage

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I have managed to show variants as seperate listings on collection page but now I want to show individual variants on the homepage. I added a featured products section and selected a collection but only the main product listing is showing (Not the variants). Any ideas?

using Dawn theme V11

I tried adding a featured products section and selected a collection but the main product listing are only showing (Not the variants). Any ideas?